# Нужна ли обратная связь в мобильном приложении?

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, ios, iphone

Доброго времени суток, Господа!
Только что поучаствовал в споре — «а нужна ли обратная связь в мобильном приложении?»
Я с читаю что нужна, потому что когда я пользуюсь приложениями, иногда возникает необходимость сообщить о каком то баге, неудобстве или еще о чем-нибудь, но очень редко встречается, что приложение имеет такую функцию, а идти на маркет, искать это приложение и писать туда отзыв, не очень приятное занятие(я ленивый). Так вот, может у кого-то был уже подобный опыт или кто-то сталкивался с таким вопросом и к чему это привело, поделитесь пожалуйста.

Какие аргументы мне привели против:
— слишком навязчиво получается, если по-твоему… Ты с хабра! Ты учить будешь! А мне не надо ниче.

**PS:** моя идея реализации такова: текстбокс и кнопка отправить, никаких пользовательских данных передаваться не будет.

Comment: *(IMHO)*

- Отправка логов исключительных ситуаций и форма обратной связи на сайте приложения покрывают 95% необходимых случаев.

- В приложении можно оставить только пункт с  семантикой `Send information to developes` и отразить это в `EULA` (или каким-то другим путем), поскольку фактически речь идет о предоставлении пользовательских данных третьим лицам.

Comment: данных никаких передаваться не будет.
Выглядеть это будет как текстбокс и кнопка отправить и больше ничего.

Comment: @Макс Ровкин Да никто не будет с мобильного девайса пользоваться формой обратной связи, где нужно что-то писать. Вы сами-то пробовали набирать на андроиде текст хотя бы в 2 абзаца длиной?

Comment: естественно пробовал, дело не только в андроиде, есть и другие ОС.
нужна ли обратная связь вообще в таком виде.

Comment: @Макс Ровкин Ладно, какой-то неконструктивный разговор получается, посмотрим, что вам ответят остальные пользователи данного ресурса.

Comment: Лучше бы вы вставили туда кнопку Tell a Friend через Intents. Гораздо полезнее чем слушать вопли over 9000 пользователей. Если хотите качественной обратной связи лучше покажите приложение паре профессиональных программистов.

Comment: Я такое навязчивое приложение сразу удалю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С одной стороны фидбек, особенно быстрый, всегда важен, с другой стороны на почту с большой долей вероятности -будет сыпаться много спама, который придётся фильтровать, но думаю будут и полезные письма. Мой выбор - такая форма нужна, но находится она должна, где-то в настройках.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю как там насчет WP7 и iOS, но в Android:

1. Возможность фидбека при падении приложения по умолчанию встроена в Android, при согласии юзера крэш репорт отсылается разработчику
2. Для Android существует огромное количество либ/инструментов для организации обратной связи - в основном они используются для маркетинга, выдачи рекламных баннеров (в зависимости от страны, аппарата, сети и проч.) - бессмысленно их перечислять, достаточно погуглить
3. Google недавно запустил сервис [Google Cloud Messaging](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/support/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=2663268), который позволяет пересылать девелоперу сообщения в свою аппу

В общем и целом в сумме, рынок движется в сторону интенсификации связи приложение <-> девелопер. Так что считаю, это нужная и полезная штука.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию, но сейчас не важна реализация, а нужно ли вообще это.

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас работаю над IOS приложением где на каждом контроллере маленькая кнопка инфо в углу. По нажатию открывается форма обратной связи с разработчиками. Это было требованием по тз и я считаю это абсолютно верным, так как Вы как разработчик получаете возможность быстрого и вероятно всеобъемлющего тестирования ресурсами других людей, и возможность быстро залатать баги или протестить функционал при внедрении обновления например. Плюс меньше будет негативных отзывов в аппсторе если все же будут баги. А чтобы ненавязчиво было - подключайте UI дизайнера. И все будет отлично

Comment: тестировать на клиентах (платящих) - дурной тон.

Comment: Ну это же значит что как только пользователь откроет приложение ему на весь экран откроется форма отправки фидбека. Сделать так чтобы это не было навязчивым - важно, но и упускать такую возможность не нужно. Более того - преподнесите ее как возможность дать совет разработчикам чего еще не хватает или что лучше исправить. Люди любят возможность почувствовать себя вложившими вклад в развитие продукта которым они пользуются

Comment: Не претендую на единственно правильное мнение, но лучше, имхо, для фидбэков иметь отдельное место. Например на android.mobile-review.com разработчики приложений выкладывают инфу о своих разработках, там люди комментируют, пишут о багах, предложениях. такой вариант выглядит более выигрышным. Все-таки писать фидбэк - дополнительное телодвижение, на которое способны далеко не все и далеко не все пользуются этой возможностью. А кнопка отправить отчет об ошибке - выглядит как "это альфа, мы ее ваще не тестировали, нам лень".

Comment: Уверен что это все только вопрос правильной подачи пользователю, но спорить тоже не буду. Надеюсь из нашей дискуссии автор вопроса сможет почерпнуть для себя информацию для размышлений

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО, возможность фидбека была бы не плохой, однако любые отчеты об ошибках должны отправляться в автоматическом режиме, либо с разрешения пользователя(для экономии трафика).

Также хочу уточнить пользовательские данные ДОЛЖНЫ отправляться. Будь то id телефона или же уникальный id для копии приложения. Как минимум это должно быть реализовано для банально защиты от флуда в фидбек и соответственно реализованы механизмы его предотвращения на сервере и возможно в приложении.

Так же я считаю что фидбек не должен находится на видном месте и мозолить глаза пользователя. Лучшим вариантом запрятать эту функцию куда нибудь в настройки или же в информацию о ПО. Возможно даже лучшим вариантом было бы простая ссылка на очень легкую страницу для фидбека.

Повторяю все вышеописанное - мое мнение и не претендует на истину.